# Retain pending edit suggestions if a post is migrated

Tags: feature-request, migration, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit on a [question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69332/htaccess-file-isnt-working-but-did-work-before?noredirect=1) just before it was migrated to Webmasters. The [suggestion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/841) was rejected (although no reviewers are listed), and it never made it to Webmasters, so I had to re-submit the edit there.

This is probably a rare case, but is it possible to migrate a pending edit suggestion on a post if that post gets migrated elsewhere?