# Migrating mod should have temporary edit privileges

Tags: feature-request, edits, migration, privileges, moderators

When a question is migrated to another site, a few things then (usually) need to be done to it:

- It must be edited to have enough background information, and be reasonably worded, for the new site.
- It needs retagging.
- Comments should be deleted as obsolete (usually the ones about topicality and migration).

Of those three, the target site's denizens can perform the last two — retagging and comment deletion. In fact, even if someone from the migrating site does those, someone from the target site should check them. But *editing for background information is best done by someone from the migrating site*. Things that are completely clear on the migrating site, that any user there will understand, may be completely opaque to most users on the target site. ([Example.](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2968)) It is therefore in the target site's best interests for someone from the migrating site to edit the question on arrival.

I propose that, when a diamond mod effects a migration, he have five minutes' edit privileges on that question only.

Even if, as [hjpotter92](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/212576/hjpotter92) suggested in a comment on this question, the mod should edit before migration, such temporary privileges would be very useful in case he didn't do so.

Comment: Edit and then migrate?

Comment: @hjpotter92, possible, but (a) sometimes you want to migrate fast, before there's more activity locally, and (b) technically the question is worded well for the migrating site (so no need to edit there).

Comment: An alternate idea would be for migration to include a way to attach a "for mod eyes only" comment.  But I think editing on the receiving site is better.

Comment: @hjpotter92, also, even if we grant that a migrating mod should edit before migration, what if he didn't? The five minutes' edit privileges would be very useful then.

Comment: Why are you assuming the moderator from the source site will even have an account on the target site?

Comment: @Yannis If you're migrating there, you should probably know *something* about the target site beyond the FAQ.

Comment: No, not necessarily @Undo. If a moderator of the target site asks for the question, for example, I'll just send it, and I couldn't care less for what the target site is about.

Comment: @Yannis Isn't that different, though? That's a mod looking at something and saying '*hey, that belongs on my site!'* vs. 'hey, this doesn't belong here, so I'll send it to the nearest place that looks like it will take it.'

Comment: @Undo "hey, this doesn't belong here, so I'll send it to the nearest place that looks like it will take it." doesn't really happen.

Comment: @Yannis I know - I was just trying to make a distinction between the two.

Comment: @Undo I got that and I'm telling you that the distinction you are trying to make doesn't exist. If we migrate a question, we were either asked to or feel reasonably confident that it belongs to the target site. Neither requires having an account on the target site.

Comment: @Yannis OK. You win. In case you can't tell, I'm not a mod anywhere.

Comment: Oh my, what's my prize @Undo? ;) Wasn't trying to win, just explain my position, and that's only because I thought your comment was reasonable. Now, I'm more or less familiar with the topics of 30 or so SE sites, but I don't have accounts on most of them (e.g. Robotics, Reverse Engineering, Open Data, Freelancing). The proposed feature wouldn't work for me if I was migrating a question from Programmers to any of those sites. All that said, random's answer beautifully explains why this feature isn't particularly useful. My comment was just a minor detail.

Answer (score 6):

While I like the idea, and have certainly fallen afoul of this myself, here's what I do these days: I edit first.

If you want to do it fast, just lock it first.

If you forget to edit first, simply submit a suggested edit. Others will approve it quickly.

Comment: Not on the smaller sites - edit can take *hours* to get through.

Comment: @undo usually we ask before migration to smaller sites, or not migrate at all. In this way, the migration usually occurs when there's a mod around.

Answer (score 6):

When you send a question over the fence of another site it should be dressed up as best you can fit it.

Otherwise, if there are edits you need to do, but you're waiting until it's on someone else's porch, it's akin to migrating crap, lighting the bag and then having second thoughts about it before you stomp it out.

Remember, when you migrate a question, you migrate the answers along with it. So there's no need to rush it so fast you can't give it at least [a once over edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/retain-pending-edit-suggestions-if-a-post-is-migrated).

Migrated questions allow for a rebirth. Don't cover its first turn at a new site in placenta and entrails because you had a stopwatch.

Comment: Your metaphors are... beautiful.